# Convert complex Java map to Json using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to convert a Java Map (with a List of MyClass values) to json using gson.

```
Map<Integer, List<MyClass>> myMap
```

Here is how I am doing it...

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
String json = gson.toJson(myMap);
System.out.println(json);
```

It produces json that is close to, but not in the format I would expect/want. Here is what is produced:

> {"0":[{MyClassItem1}, {MyClassItem2}, etc],  "1":[{MyClassItem3},
>   {MyClassItem4}, etc],  etc... }

I would expect/prefer it produces:

> [{"0":[{MyClassItem1}, {MyClassItem2}, etc]}, {"1":[{MyClassItem3},
>   {MyClassItem4}, etc]}, etc...]

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Well... Gson serializes data to its most appropriate form. It seems that you want an array of `Map.Entry`. Try something like:

```
Map<Integer, List<MyClass>> myMap = ...;
Set<Map.Entry<Integer, List<MyClass>>> entrySet = myMap.entrySet();
Object[] data = entrySet.toArray(new Object[entrySet.size()]);

// serialize data variable
```

However be aware that Gson might not be able to serialize `Map.Entry` out-of-the-box.